# Python and list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
s = [64, 128]
a = [[]] * len(s)
print(a)
print(a[0])
a[0].append([1,2])
print(a)
```

If I run it, I get this:

```
[[], []]
[]
[[[1, 2]], [[1, 2]]]
```

So `a` is a list of list, initialized with two empty lists.

I append the list `[1,2]` to `a[0]`, which, in my intentions, would be the first empty list.

I was expecting `a` to be equal to `[ [ [1,2] ], [] ]`.

Is there anyone who can help me?

1) Why did I get that `[ [1,2], [1,2] ]`?

2) How can I assign `[1,2]` to the first list in the list of lists `a`?

Comment: @MattR this is yet another story; it inserts a third list. Don't confuse OP even more.

Comment: @Antonio It's basically the same list repeated thrice when you do [[]]*3. So when you alter one inner list, all will be altered. Basically changing this condition to a =[[],[],[]] will fix it. You can also generate innerlists within a loop to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I have read the original question pointed out by Kevin and understood why. Thanks. I searched it but could not find that specific question: sorry for repeating.